# Session usage details or implementation details of ngdbc.jar

Tags: sqoop, hana

I am pulling data from Hana onto Hadoop. I am using sqoop 1.4.4-mapr-1408. The Hana Connection is setup using a JDBC connection in Sqoop using a Jar file provided by SAP Hana - ngdbc.jar.

Now the question is -

1. How does the jar interact with SAP Hana?
2. Does it fetch the entire table in memory or will it fetch only the a certain batch size in memory?
3. How can these stats be measured on our system from HANA end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The .jar archive contain the native JAVA JDBC implementation of the
   SAP HANA wire protocol. See the documentation for that here:
   http://help.sap.com/hana/SAP_HANA_SQL_Command_Network_Protocol_Reference_en.pdf
   There's not much "magic" to it - but it's a fairly optimised JDBC 4
   implementation.

   2. The JDBC driver doesn't fetch tables at all. Tables never leave the database. What you get from the driver is result sets. If you're query stupid-simply reads a whole table, then the driver will provide the result set accordingly. 
      This of course doesn't happen at once, so you don't need to "drink water from the hose". The open-fetch-next cycle you have to implement in your client code is translated by the driver into a similar chunk-wise transfer from the server to the client. The chunk-size for this (chunk size) is typically set automatically and could be set via the JDBC API.
   3. You can use JDBC performance trace and the network statistics on the SAP HANA server.

Considering that you seem to dump data from HANA to HADOOP, then the good news is that the batch size is automatically set to the maximum value given the client's network setup. 
Most likely the time for your data dump will be spend with materialising large result sets. Dumping tables is actually the anti-use case for HANA, which is why it is one of the slowest things you could do.

my 2 cts.

Comment: Thanks Lars. When you say "materializing large result sets" can you explain some more. Also what happens in case of Views - how is that process optimized?

Comment: Materialisation is the process of turning the internal data structures (column store) into a result set. As this whole topic is quite complex, I cannot go over it just here, 
You might want to educate yourself more on the inner workings of SAP HANA, e.g, via scn.sap.com or maybe my book :-)

Comment: Wow! That's cool! I have friends who work on HANA - this will be interesting to them.